# Email accounts suddenly disappear from Samsung stock client

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, email, clockworkmod-recovery, imap

I have a Samsung Galaxy S, rooted with ClockworkMod a good while ago. Since about two months, my imap accounts spontaneously disappear from the Samsung stock email.

When launched, the email app asks me if I want to configure it with an account.

I have [heard](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-skyrocket/587069-email-client-in-ics-keeps-deleting-email-accounts.html) [from](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=32927407#post32927407) [other](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/567129-imap-email-account-disappears-every-couple-days.html) people experiencing this, but never discovered a solution.

Comment: May I suggest switching to CM9 and/or the stock Android mail client? Switching to CM9 was the best decision I ever made with my Galaxy S.

Comment: I am not against this. I was considering CWM10 though.(Reason for 9?). This doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: That's why I made it a comment. There is no stable marked CM10 release for the SGS (yet). And the improvements are minor. That's why I suggest CM9 (9.1.0 to be precise).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but you might be confusing Cyangenmod with Clockworkmod. Clockworkmod is just a rooted version of the samsung android.

Comment: No no, I really suggest you try out Cyanogenmod 9.1.0 for the Galaxy S in case you are still on the bloated Samsung stock firmware.

Comment: I WILL do it, maybe today or tomorrow. But this doesn't solve the question, it just circumvents the problem for me.

Comment: I know. But I think that's it's likely that our never find a answer to your question, plus the stock client or k9 are far superior to the Samsung client (IMHO).